# A set that is an element of itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A_1 = \left\{ 5 \right\}$ and that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ A_{n+1} = \left\{ A_{n} \right\}.$$

Now consider the set
$$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal P (A_n).$$

Is it true that $A \in A$? It seems like it is, but that doesn't seem right!

Comment: See: [Axiom of regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: Why does it seem to you like $A\in A$? That $A\in A$ means that $A\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\mathcal P(A_n)$, which means that $A\in\mathcal P(A_n)$ for some $n$, which means that $A\subseteq A_n$ for some $n$. For which $n$ does it seem to you that $A\subseteq A_n$? How could $A$ possibly be a subset of $A_n$, seeing as $A_n$ has only one element, while $A$ has infinitely many elements?

Comment: I really like this proof.... you should write it as an answer.

Comment: I am surprised Bourbaki is asking a question on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Given any singleton $X = \{ x \}$, the power set is $\mathcal{P}(X) = \{ \varnothing, \{ x \} \}$.

Here, $\mathcal{P}(A_n) = \{ \varnothing, \{A_{n-1}\} \}$ if $n > 1$ and $\mathcal{P}(A_1) = \{ \varnothing, \{5\} \}$. Hence
$$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{P}(A_n) = \{ \varnothing,\ \{ 5 \},\ \{\{5\}\},\ \{\{\{5\}\}\},\ \cdots \}$$

Is $A \in A$? Every element of $A$ is finite, but $A$ is infinite, so we can't have $A \in A$.